# Edit page is not working DNN 7.00.05

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have downloaded latest version of DNN7(7.00.05) & configured it correctly on localhost as described in installation video but while clicking on edit page from menu item I was redirected on home page . I have repeated installation process many times to resolve this. but still this issue appears on edit page functionality. it is frustrating now.

Any one have solution of this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following solution

Go to web.config and find `<modules>` section under `<system.webServer>` and add following key value .

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >`

This will be solved your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Post, This is working Perfectly. 
I have added runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in web.config and my both issues(Edit Page & Add New Module) has been resolved. In my web.config I have added like this:-

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  ...
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to overcome the issue

1. Allow 4.0 version in ISAPI of IIS
2. Point your code as a virtual directory to the website in IIS with localhost
3. Click on website in IIS and select edit permissions from explore option of IIS and add full permission to the folder from security tab.
4. Restart the instance and browse from IIS using manage website option in IIS

That should do !!!!